# Flutter: 3 positional argument(s) expected, but 0 found

Tags: flutter, dart, parameters, arguments

I am very new to Dart, and coding in general.
I have produced this code after watching tutorials on YouTube. For the most part I have been able to troubleshoot most of my problems on my own, yet I cannot figure out my most recent errors.
The error messages are for 'body.dart', and they are related to positional arguments and undefined parameters.
Any help would be greatly appreciated,
I have left the code, which I believe is necessary, down below.
Thanks.

This is my body.dart file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:language_app/components/default_button.dart';
import 'package:language_app/constants.dart';
import 'package:language_app/size.config.dart';
import '../components/splash_content.dart';



class Body extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BodyState createState() => _BodyState();
}

class _BodyState extends State<Body> {
  int currentPage = 0;
  List<Map<String, String>> splashData = [
    {
      "text": "Buongiorno",
      "image": "build/images/splash_1.png"
    },
    {
      "text": "Hallo",
      "image": "build/images/splash_2.png"
    },
    {
      "text": "Hola",
      "image": "build/images/splash_3.png"
    },
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: SizedBox(
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
                flex: 3,
                child: PageView.builder(
                  onPageChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      currentPage = value;
                    });
                  },
                  itemCount: splashData.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) => SplashContent(
                    image: splashData[index]["image"],
                    text: splashData[index]["text"],
                      ),
                )),
            Expanded(
              flex: 2,
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: getProportionateScreenWidth(20)),
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Spacer(),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: List.generate(
                        splashData.length,
                            (index) => buildDot(index: index),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Spacer(flex: 3),
                    DefaultButton(
                      text: "Continue",
                      press: () {},
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  AnimatedContainer buildDot(int index) {
    return AnimatedContainer(
      duration: kAnimationDuration,
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5),
      height: 6,
      width: currentPage == index ? 20 : 6,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: currentPage == index ? kPrimaryColor : Color(0xFFD8D8D8),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Android studio gives my the following error messages:

3 positional argument(s) expected, but 0 found.:46
The named parameter 'image' isn't defined.:47
The named parameter 'text' isn't defined.:48
1 positional argument(s) expected, but 0 found.:62
The named parameter 'index' isn't defined.:62
3 positional argument(s) expected, but 0 found.:66
The named parameter 'text' isn't defined.:67
The named parameter 'press' isn't defined.:68

This is the extraction of my SplashContent widget, which is in a separate .dart file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:language_app/constants.dart';
import 'package:language_app/size.config.dart';

class SplashContent extends StatelessWidget {
  const SplashContent(
      Key key,
    this.text,
    this.image,
) : super(key: key);
  final String text, image;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Spacer(),
        Text(
          "Ah Oui",
          style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: getProportionateScreenWidth(36),
          color: kPrimaryColor,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        ),
        ),
        Text(
          text,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
        Spacer(flex:2),
        Image.asset(
          image,
          height: getProportionateScreenHeight(265),
          width: getProportionateScreenWidth(235),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

and this is the extraction of my DefaultButton widget, which is also in a separate .dart file:

```
class DefaultButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const DefaultButton(
    Key key,
    this.text,
    this.press,
  ) : super(key: key);
  final String text;
  final VoidCallback press;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: getProportionateScreenHeight(56),
      child: TextButton(
        onPressed: press,
        child: Text(
          text,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: getProportionateScreenWidth(18),
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Constructor in `DefaultButton` & `SplashContent` uses Positional Parameter. Instances of these widgets are trying to use named parameter in `_BodyState`.

**Solution 1**

Change the usage of `DefaultButton` & `SplashContent` as follows, that way positional parameters would be used.

```dart
DefaultButton(UniqueKey(), "Continue", () {}),

SplashContent(UniqueKey(), splashData[index]["image"], splashData[index]["text"]),
```

**Solution 2**

Use named parameters by using braces in the constructors. No need to change the code in `_BodyState` and that way named parameters would be used.

Answer (score 0):

**change.**
final String text, image;
**to**
final String **?** text, image;
**and change**
text to **text!** and image to **image!**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).